# Reversed array does not contain every element

Tags: javascript, web, computer-science

Why does my function return only [3, 2,]. It should print out the element 1 as well?

```
function reverseArr(arr) {
    var reverse = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        reverse.push(arr.pop());
    return reverse;
}

console.log(reverseArr([1, 2, 3]));
```

Comment: `[1,2,3].reverse()` do not reinvent the wheel

Comment: There is a [built-in function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) to reverse an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're modifying `arr` with each iteration, `arr.length` is changing. Try this instead:

```
function reverseArr(arr) {
    var reverse = [], len = arr.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
        reverse.push(arr.pop());
    return reverse;
}
```

Note, however, this will modify the original array, which is probably not what you intended. If you'd like to preserve the original array, use [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) instead:

```
function reverseArr(arr) {
    var reverse = [], len = arr.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
        reverse.unshift(arr[i]);
    return reverse;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a combination of [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) to return a new, reversed copy of the input array without modifying the original:

```
function reverseArr(arr) {
    return arr.slice().reverse();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're changing the length of the array as you pop off of it. So `arr.length` starts at 3 then 2 then 1. Instead, you could do something like this:

```
function reverseArr(arr) {
    var reverse = [];
    while (arr.length) {
        reverse.push(arr.pop());
    }
    return reverse;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or

```
function reverseArr(arr) {
    var reverse = [];
    while (arr.length > 0)
        reverse.push(arr.pop());
    return reverse;
}
```

Or

```
function reverseArr(arr) {
    var reverse = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        reverse.push(arr[arr.length - 1 - i]);
    return reverse;
}
```

Or simply `arr.reverse()`